# How to query an API repeatedly and append each JSON response to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, dataframe

I'm trying to aggregate multiple years worth of data from the EPA's air quality API. The API returns a JSON file for each year, which I would like to convert to a dataframe, ultimately appending each subsequent year to the same dataframe. Here's my code:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 60)

i = 1999

for i in range(1999, 2020):

    parameters = {
        "email": "patrick.debiasse@gmail.com",
        "key": "khakihawk63",
        "param": "81104,44201,42602,42101,42401",
        "bdate": str(i) + "1201",
        "edate": str(i) + "1202",
        "state": "49",
        "county": "035",
        "site": "3006"
    }

    #requesting the JSON data
    json_data = requests.get("https://aqs.epa.gov/data/api/annualData/bySite email=test@aqs.api&key=test&param=44201&bdate=20170618&edate=20170618&state=37&county=183&site=0014", params=parameters).json()

    #converting to dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame((json_data['Data']))

    #appending the converted data to a separate dataframe which will ultimately contain all the years' data
    df2 = df.append(df)

    i + 1

df2
```

When I run the above code I only see data for the last year (2019) in the "df2" dataframe, and it seems to be included twice (2019 data appended to 2019 data). Am I making some novice for loop mistake here? Not appending the data correctly? Something else I'm not considering? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently append the dataframe to itself in every loop and assign it to the df2 variable.

Instead try this:

```
for i in range(1999, 2020):

    ...

    #converting to dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame((json_data['Data']))

    #appending the converted data to a separate dataframe which will ultimately contain all the years' data
    if i == 1999:
        result = df
    else:
        result = result.append(df)
```

I also don't understand why you have the statement `i + 1` at the end to the for loop. The for loop itself takes care of increasing the counter and you don't need to do that. If you would want to skip one year, you could use `range(1999, 2020, 2)` instead.
Also, the way you wrote it `i` doesn't get increased, you would need to write `i += 1`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. That was helpful, but the "result" dataframe only has data from 1999...what might be causing this?

Comment: My bad. It should be `result = result.append (df)`